# How to replace command line arguments sys.argv by stdin stdout?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, sys

I realize, that my question is a very simple one, but I can't find any explicit example of the implementation of the stdin stdout into a Python script.

I have a script, working perfectly well with command line arguments:

```
newlist = []
def f1()
  .... 
def f2(input_file):
  vol_id = sys.argv[3]
  for line in input_file:
      if ... :
        line = line.replace('abc','def')
        line = line.replace('id', 'id'+vol_id)
      ....
      newlist.append(line)
   return newlist

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 4:
       print 'usage: ./myscript.py [file_in... file_out... volume_id]'
       sys.exit(1)

    else:

        filename = sys.argv[1]
        filename_out = sys.argv[2]


        tree = etree.parse(filename)
        extract(tree)

        input_file = open(filename, 'rU')
        change_class(input_file)

        file_new = open(filename_out, 'w')
        for x in newlist:

            if '\n' in x:                   
               x = x.replace('\n', '')                
            print>>file_new, x
```

Now I should somehow use stdin and stdout instead of my arguments in order to make my script usable within pipelines, like for example using multiple files as input:

> > cat input1 input1 input3 | myscript.py

Or to process its output with some UNIX tools before printing it to a file. 
I tried to replace arguments in my script by sys.stdin:

```
filename = sys.stdin
filename_out = sys.stdout
```

Then I ran my script like this:

> > ./myscript.py < inputfile > outputfile

It resulted in an empty outputfile, but didn't yeld any error messages at all.

Could you please help me with this replacement?

P.S. Then I modified my main() like this:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
filename_out = sys.argv[2]

if filename == '-':
   filename = sys.stdin
else:
    input_file = open(filename, 'rU')


if filename_out == '-':
    filename_out = sys.stdout
    file_new = filename_out
else:
    file_new = open(filename_out, 'w')


tree = etree.parse(filename)
extract(tree)

input_file = filename
change_class(input_file)

for x in newlist:

    if '\n' in x:                   
       x = x.replace('\n', '')                
    print>>file_new, x
```

I tried to run it from the command line like this:

```
./myscript.py - - volumeid < filein > fileout
```

But I still got an empty output file :(

Comment: You might find the `fileinput` module useful (in the standard library).

Comment: @cdarke: `fileinput` is great for when all you have is input files. You'd still have to handle the command line arguments manually and pass in the files `fileinput` should treat as input explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common placeholder for `stdin` or `stdout` is `-`:

```
./myscript.py - - volumeid
```

and:

```
if filename == '-':
    input_file = sys.stdin
else:
    input_file = open(filename, 'rU')
```

etc.

In addition, you could default `filename` and `filename_out` to `-` when there are fewer than 3 command line arguments. You should consider using a dedicated command-line argument parser such as [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html), which can handle these cases for you, including defaulting to `stdin` and `stdout`, and using `-`.

As a side note, I'd not use `print` to write to a file; I'd just use:

```
file_new.write(x)
```

which removes the need to strip off the newlines as well.

You appear to read from the input file twice; once to parse the XML tree, once again to call `change_class()` with the open file object. What are you trying to do there? You'll have problems replicating that with `sys.stdin` as you cannot re-read the data from a stream the way you can from a file on disk.

You'd have to read all the data into memory first, then parse the XML from it, then read it it again for `change_class()`. It'd be better if you used the parsed XML tree for this instead, if possible (e.g. read the file only once, then use the parsed structure from there on out).

Comment: Comments are not the best place to post code. If the follow-up question involves more that a small clarification, it could be that a new question needs to be asked instead.

Comment: exactly! thats why I put my code as an answer below

Comment: Ah, use answers for actual answers *only*!

Comment: and answers with equal votes are sorted randomly, so I did not see your answer 'below' but 'above'.

Comment: OK, question modified

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with your code; add some `print` statements to verify that your assumptions are correct, perhaps.

Comment: @elaine_blath: ah, no, I see what goes wrong; you cannot 'reread' the stdin twice here. You are reading `inputfile` when parsing the XML, then reading it *again* to call `change_class`; what are you trying to do there?

Comment: I also thought that it was probably connected to the fact that I use the same input file twice... But it worked with sys.argv ...

Comment: @elaine_blath: That's because you opened the file twice in your code (with the `etree.parse()` call opening it for you first, you explicitly opening it a second time after that).

Comment: I first use an XML parser in f1() in order to extract 3 lists of definitions, then in f2() I compare the items in these lists to the initial file and change class values in it, according to my 3 lists

Comment: @elaine_blath: Then the only option you have is to first read all data from the input file in a string, then re-use that string for both parsing and comparing (using `etree.fromstring()` instead of `etree.parse()`, IIRC).

Comment: I made these changes, now I have other problems - I will modify my question in a minute

Comment: Please don't. Create a new question instead; Stack Overflow is not suited for morphing questions.

Comment: Here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911323/stdin-stdout-python-how-to-reuse-the-same-input-file-twice  I  hope you will take a look at it as well.